# Montar data/hora a partir de mês informado pelo usuário

Tags: php

Tenho o mês inserido pelo o usuário. ex:

```
$mes = 11;
```

Agora quero pegar esse mês e retornar o (dia/ano/hora) atual + o mês informado:

```
2015-11-08 14:44:00
```

Comment: E de onde vêm a informação do dia e hora? tanto faz ou também vem do utilizador? em que formato?

Comment: quero pegar a data/hora atual do servidor mesmo.

Comment: E que formato de saida queres? unix timestamp ou formatada?

Comment: @Sergio unix timestamp

Comment: @Earendul o dia/ano/hora é do mês atual. Só o mês é informado pelo o usuário.

Comment: Entendi, achei que vc queria o tempo atual. Então não seria atual se o usuário informasse um mês que já passou ou está por vir..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dá pra ser feito assim.

```
$data = date("Y-".$mes_informado."-d H:i:s")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
<?php

$mes = 11;
$data = substr_replace( date( 'Y--d H:i:s' ), $mes, 5, 0 );
```